# How can i put my Code together in Python?

Tags: python

I make a discord bot and one funtion is that you can get stats for champions from the game League of Legends, now i have 3 code parts that are actually the same, there are just 2 things that are different. Is it possible to make a for loop or something like that to put them in on function?

```
#winrate
elem = soup.find_all("tr", {"id": "statistics-win-rate-row"})
table = str(elem[0])
tablerow = table.splitlines()
for item in tablerow:
    if "%" in item:
        item = item.replace(" ", "")
        winrate = item
        break

#playrate
elem = soup.find_all("tr", {"id": "statistics-play-rate-row"})
table = str(elem[0])
tablerow = table.splitlines()
for item in tablerow:
    if "%" in item:
        item = item.replace(" ", "")
        playrate = item
        break

#banrate
elem = soup.find_all("tr", {"id": "statistics-ban-rate-row-row"})
table = str(elem[0])
tablerow = table.splitlines()
for item in tablerow:
    if "%" in item:
        item = item.replace(" ", "")
        banrate = item
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing such problems try to search for the common parts of your code, I mean, things that are doing repeated worked, but named differently. You have remarked yourself that "3 code parts area actually the same". That is exactly a good case for refactoring it into a function. Here is my suggestion:

```
def get_item_for(id):
    elem = soup.find_all("tr", {"id": id})
    table = str(elem[0])
    tablerow = table.splitlines()
    for item in tablerow:
        if "%" in item:
            return item.replace(" ", "")

winrate = get_item_for("statistics-win-rate-row")
playrate = get_item_for("statistics-play-rate-row")
banrate = get_item_for("statistics-ban-rate-row-row")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a function which has an argument which has a flag which triggers special operation, like:

```
def function(flag):
        # code
        if(flag == 1):
            winrate = item
        elif(flag == 2):
            playrate = item
        elif(flag == 3):
            banrate = item
        #rest of the code
```